# Undefined reference to defined local variable

Tags: c, sfml

I am doing the SFML tutorial but adapting it to C

I declare a variable in the code and using it elsewhere, but getting a gcc error that says `undefined reference to 'mainWindow'`

Code:

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.h"

int main() {

    sfVideoMode vm = {200, 200};
    char* title = "CSFML Works!";

    sfRenderWindow mainWindow(vm, title);
    sfRenderWindow* window = &mainWindow;

    float size = 100;
    sfCircleShape shape(size);

    while(sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window)) {
        sfEvent event;
        while(sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, &event)) {
            if(event.type == sfClose) {
                sfRenderWindow_close(window);
            }
        }

        sfRenderWindow_clear(window, sfBlack);
        sfRenderWindow_drawCircleShape(window, shape, NULL);
        sfRenderWindow_display(window);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sfRenderWindow mainWindow(vm, title);` is a function prototype, not a variable definition. The identifier `mainWindow` is not pre-defined, so you have to either define the function yourself, or tell the linker what library it lives in (with gcc via the `-l...` flag)

Comment: @pmg when I go to definition of `sfRenderWindow` i get `typedef struct sfRenderWindow sfRenderWindow;`, so I am assuming its a struct, and is not meant to be a function

Comment: The prototype `sfRenderWindow mainWindow(vm, title);` says that `mainWindow` is a function that takes two arguments (of types `vm` and `title`) and returns a `sfRenderWindow`

Comment: @pmg how would I go about initializing a struct variable with fields `sfVideoMode` and `char*`?

Comment: The most direct way is with "designated initializers" `struct whatever variable = { .sfVideoMode_membername = 42, .charpointer_membername = NULL };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C libraries for CSFML contains a function to initialize a window like so, I was declaring it like a function prototype

```
window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, title, style, settings);
```